# Android Webview Authentication via Javascript prompt

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I was working on creating an app on Android which basically is a simple webview of a website. At a certain point in the website, on clicking a link it gives a JS prompt asking for authentication credentials. I am having problems in displaying the JS prompt in my web view.

```js
public class IASCActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        
        //WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        //webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://iasc.hsutx.edu/");
       
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you ask for authentication at the startup of the app? that way you can have custom view asking for credentials before showing up anything else or if you are fetching mobile version of your web-site, create separate login page.

Comment: Well, i can ask for the credentials in the beginning but then i have no idea how to parse the credentials into the js prompt. The page just then throws a 401.2 error. Also, the website is not made by me. I cannot alter it.

Comment: So either i enable the js prompt or i parse the the credentials in js prompt. I prefer the first method. But i can also go with the second way if you can guide me through it.

Comment: I do not get the **js prompt** part. Do you mean `prompt("Enter User Id","user id")`?

Comment: Yes, It Shows a prompt in browser asking for user id and pass and has text fields corresponding to same. But I am not able to get this in webview

Comment: can you give me url of page where it asks for login?

Comment: http://iasc.hsutx.edu/panstarrs/Pan-STARRS/PS1_42/